# iPhone nativeScale is NaN

Tags: ios

I have code that checks the `UIScreen.nativeScale` vs `scale` to determine whether it is being downsampled and therefore cannot display a 0.5pt line.

```
static var lineHeight: CGFloat {
    let screen = UIScreen()

    //iPhone Plus devices have scale: 3.0, nativeScale: 2.6, displayZoom: 2.8
    return (screen.nativeScale < screen.scale) ? 1.0 : 0.5
}
```

Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html) says that the iPhone 8 has a native scale of 2.0, but when checking on the device it prints `nan`. This is the same on my iPhone 6s.

```
let screen = UIScreen()    
let message = "Scale: \(screen.scale), Native Scale: \(screen.nativeScale)"
print(message)
//prints: Scale: 2.0, Native Scale: nan
```

Is there a technical reason why the device wouldn't have a value for `nativeScale`?

Comment: Because `UIScreen()` is not your device's screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating an empty, new instance of `UIScreen`. Use `UIScreen.main` instead. That will give you the proper results.

```
let screen = UIScreen.main
```

Comment: Odd that `scale` returns the correct value, but embarrassed that I missed this. Thanks.